# Can't access youtube api's player object's functions

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm following [this Youtube API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById), and I'm stuck at the part where I can controll the playback of the video. The video is loading and everything, just its functions aren't working properly. Here's a screenshot that explains the problem:

var `player` is supposed to have a functions like `stopVideo()`, but it either doesn't or for some reason I can't access them this way.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]